# Adobe Analytics "Product Views" greater than "Page Views"

Tags: adobe-analytics, web-analytics

[Adobe Analytics Metrics Reference][1]https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/metrics.html

According to the definitions of Page Views and Product Views and in an e-commerce perspective, a page view is being set for each server call that is sent and a Product View is is set when a product detail page is being viewed. Given that my product detail page is also a page view, page views should always be greater than the product view. But, in some of my instances I can find my product views being greater than the page views. Is there any specific reason how that could happen?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a 1:1 relationship with product views and page views. It is possible to have more product views if you have more than one product in the `products` string, or if you pop `prodView` more than once on a page. For example, maybe you have a product listing page with quickview buttons and you trigger `prodView` on them.  Especially if you trigger those `prodViews` as `s.tl` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Also, product views (specifically, prodView instead of a custom event) can sometimes be triggered if you set the products string WITHOUT setting the events string on a page. I believe there is a now a setting on the backend that can control whether or not this happens, but historically this has been a frequent cause of prodViews being higher than expected.